# Download Internet Explorer for Windows 8

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I'd like to install the 11th version of Internet Explorer.

[website](http://windows.microsoft.com/fr-fr/internet-explorer/ie-11-worldwide-languages)

My system is Windows 8 64-bit.

I can't find the suitable download link!!

1. Does internet explorer 11 have no version compatible with Windows 8?
2. Otherwise, how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no IE11 for Windows 8 because [it doesn't run on Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-system-requirements#ie=ie-11), as Ramhound pointed out in comments. To get it, you must upgrade to Windows 8.1 and it will be automatically installed.

Another option is to downgrade to Windows 7, where you can install it via Windows Update or through the [Microsoft website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-11-worldwide-languages).